# R data table, how to create a new column, where the answer is dependent to Another column within the DT

Tags: r, datatable

Hi I want to create a new column, whose answer are based on another column in my Existing DT. 
I would like to use functions within the data table parameter to maximise efficiency.

```
smoked <- matrix(c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","B","A"),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(smoked) <- c("Type","Name","cusip")
rownames(smoked) <- c("A","B","C")
smoked <- as.table(smoked)
smoked
```

How would i create a another column that that responds "B" every occasion the condition is met within the "name" column.. and then "not B" for every occasion it does not.

Comment: Your shown code doesn't create a data table. Could you be more precise on your "conditions"? What is your expected output?

Comment: dt <- data.table(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                                  type= c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                                 Cusip = c("A", "B", "C"))

Comment: See my answer with different data. Your shown data don't create a well defined data.table since Cusip is of length 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a *data.table*

```r
library(data.table)

smoked <- data.table(Type=c("A", "B", "A"), Name=c("A", "B", "B"), cusip=c("A", "B", "A"))

# > smoked
#    Type Name cusip
# 1:    A    A     A
# 2:    B    B     B
# 3:    A    B     A
```

and you want to create a new column based on `Type` and `Name`, then

```r
smoked$NewLine <- fifelse(smoked$Type == "A" & smoked$Name == "A", "B", "not B")
```

gives you

```r
> smoked
   Type Name cusip NewLine
1:    A    A     A       B
2:    B    B     B   not B
3:    A    B     A   not B
```

Comment: My R came back with ' could not find function "fifelse" ', why could this be?

Comment: `fifelse` is part of the library `data.table`. Are you sure you are using `data.table` and not an ordinary data.frame?

Comment: If your are using an ordinary data.frame replace `fifelse` with `ifelse`.